# Copying data from one table to a new one, but i want the id of the user and not the username in the new one

Tags: mysql

The tables that are involved look like what is below:

**TABLE WE ARE COPYING**: (`passwordResetTable`)

```
TOKEN(VARCHAR) |  UID(VARCHAR)
```

**NEW TABLE WE ARE COPYING DATA TO** (`newPasswordResetTable`)

```
TOKEN(VARCHAR)PK   |   ADMINID(INT)FK
```

`ADMINID` is a foreign key to table admins below

```
AdminID(int)   |    Username(varchar)


insert into newPasswordResetTable(Token,AdminID)
    select Token,(select ???????????????)
    from passwordResetTable;
```

Comment: Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: How UID from passwordResetTable relates to admins table?

Comment: it does not. UID.

Comment: what is the relationship between UID and Username? Which table has that relationship?